# Delegating the clicked event to the templated control

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

Since the CheckBox control doesn't increase the checkbox when the font size is increased, I decided to create my own variation of it (since it's to be used on a touch screen).

I have the following template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="YesNoCheckbox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Name="myButton"/>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="myButton" Value="Ja"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="myButton" Value="Nei"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, I need to delegate the click event from the button to the checkbox, so that the checked state is checked/unchecked.

I'm a total newbie, and this is probably very easy, but I fail to search this information up, probably due to a lack of correct keywords to search for.

I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CheckBox` is a `ToggleButton` by itself and you are trying to place another button inside, which is wrong.

`CheckBox` changes its `IsChecked` automatically when it gets clicked. So you don't need to define another button inside. What you need to do instead is define a visual drawing in the `CheckBox` template that will scale when the `FontSize` increases and that will reflect current `CheckBox` state. Basically, you need to modify default style.

Comment: Why is that wrong? What's the difference between this and nesting controls (e.g <TextBlock>Name:<TextBox/></TextBlock>)?

Comment: @Vincent - "<TextBlock>Name:<TextBox/></TextBlock>" is different. First of all, what you are trying to do is <Button><Button/><Button>. Does it make any sense? Second of all, don't mix logical controls composition and control templates. In WPF controls are designed to be "lookless". It means that they define their behavior (response to clicks, their state, etc) and their look is defined in their control template that you might want to change. What you need in your case is define a new look, but the behavior of the CheckBox should stay the same.